How do you access user memory in a PySpark application?
How do I access the user memory set aside in a PySpark application ?

My guess this is not possible in a PySpark application as this is part of JVM memory which is not accessible via Python.
If I am correct then in a PySpark application there is no need to set aside any memory for this correct (as its inaccesible)?

I'm afraid it is not entirely correct. pyspark interacts with the JVM's memory through py4j module, and you as well can access this memory through java gateway.
For example, lets check Spark JVM's classpath (these are all Java classes that have a  potential to be loaded into your "User memory"):
$ pyspark
Python 3.11.2 (main, Feb 17 2023, 09:28:16) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.4.0.
      /_/

Using Python version 3.11.2 (main, Feb 17 2023 09:28:16)
Spark context Web UI available at http://xxx.xxx.xxx:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_9999999999999_9999).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> 
>>> cp = spark._jvm.System.getProperty("java.class.path")
>>> for jar in sorted(cp.split(":")): print(jar)
...
/etc/hive/conf/
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/avro.jar
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.599.jar
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/aws-java-sdk-bundle.jar
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.6.jar
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/azure-data-lake-store-sdk.jar
/opt/spark340/lib/hadoop/client/checker-qual-2.8.1.jar
:
:

A side comment-- your diagram (a link to the source would've been nice!) is neither accurate nor complete. Spark uses Unified memory model since version 2.0 so there is no Execution vs Storage memory (corresponding config settings were deprecated and removed in 3.0). There is also an option to allocate memory specifically for python in pyspark. For complete list of config settings, look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties

Wait then how do I access the user memory ? Or is there no user memory ? Its just spark and storage memory ?

Roughly speaking, JVM memory (heap) is divided into Spark memory (aka unified, execution+storage, memory managed by Spark) and everything else (unmanaged, which JVM uses for stacks, threads, non-spark objects, etc, etc.. I assume this is your "user memory". Again, a link to the source of the diagram would be helpful to understand better.

Taken from here: https://youtu.be/iLpjNItogwc?t=199 Is it all wrong ?

Is there no such thing as user memory ?

I'd say outdated :)) Not necessarily wrong for when it was published. Please check this Spark doc for up-to-date info https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management

You can call a fraction of memory not owned and controlled by Spark, which is 40% of (container memory - 300 MB reserved) a "user" memory, but it will be your term not easily understood by others.

I just have one last question: this "user" or unmanaged memory, is this memory belonging to the JVM or the OS ? I mean is it "raw" memory or still managed memory by the Spark application.

It is a 40% fraction of JVM heap. Spark literally takes a 60% chunk of heap (see spark.memory.fraction) for its own needs, leaving the remaining 40% to the "user". IOW if your Spark application is loading some extra data/objects besides dataframes/RDDs, they should fit into this 40%  (I rounded off reserved 300MB)

What I don't understand is that why even after having execution memory why does it need the remaining 40% ? Why not just use the managed execution memory ?

So basically the 40% is just reserved memory that Spark ALSO ACCESSES if need be. Am I correct ? So IOW its also managed by Spark right ?

I made another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78872331/why-not-set-spark-memory-fraction-to-1-0

Roughly speaking yes. Although I would say "it is also USED by Spark" rather than managed. "Managed memory" (those 60%) means Spark itself keeps track of how much is used, can additional data block fit into it, or should it do something to free up space, write (spill) some blocks to disk or discard (LRU) some blocks completely. Remaining 40% is managed by JVM and its GC.

I am fine with accepting your explanation but can you provide me the doc or info link from where you are getting this ? Because everywhere online I can see the outdated "user" memory info. No one says Spark also access this portion. It would really help me if you could just point me to the docs. Thanks again for your patience.

Spark is a Java application (written mostly in Scala :)) As such, it requires JVM and uses JVM memory to run. One large portion of JVM memory (60%) Spark allocates for exclusive use (so it is not garbage collected) and calls it Spark memory. I don't know how else to explain that, sorry.

Here is Spark's own overview, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview.
Note that it doesnt refer to 40% as "user memory", although some people might feel fine calling it that :))

You are right : There is a line which says: "The rest of the space (40%) is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually large records." https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html
